# Heroku Rails app immediately crashes on HTTP request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, crash

My Rails app works fine locally, but not on Heroku.. I can call `heroku run rake db:migrate` and `heroku run rake db:reset` without incident, but as soon as I issue an HTTP request to the app it immediately crashes. Here's the output of `heroku info`:

```
Addons:        Basic Logging, Basic Release Management, Shared Database 5MB
Database Size: 1M
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:blazing-dawn-5661.git
Repo Size:     52M
Slug Size:     53M
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://blazing-dawn-5661.herokuapp.com/
```

Here is the output of `heroku logs` after issuing an HTTP request to the app (nothing here seems particularly helpful):

```
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f
]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[we
b.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x519499]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_yield+0x66) [0x521d56]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x51307f]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby(rb_ary_each+0x45) [0x533735]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/local/bin/ruby() [0x515546]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: [NOTE]
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Bug reports are welcome.
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
2012-03-30T13:02:13+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-03-30T13:02:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 139
2012-03-30T13:02:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Comment: What controller code is running? Do you have any before/after filters that could be causing this?

Comment: I have a before filter on one of my models, an instance of which is created in my seeds file, but that runs as part of `rake db:reset`, which does not cause the app to crash. It's only once it receives a request that it crashes, and the logs don't seem to implicate the controller.

Comment: By the output from the log, as there are no traces back to your application stack, I think that you actually have encountered a bug in ruby. You should try and report it.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Ruby both locally and on your Heroku instance?

Comment: Could you paste the output of: rake RAILS_ENV=production middleware

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this:

**Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2 on Heroku**

Heroku’s newest stack, “Celadon Cedar,” supports Rails 3.2 but installs Ruby 1.9.2 by default. Ruby 1.9.3 is recommended for Rails 3.2.

You can configure the Heroku environment to use Ruby 1.9.3.

*Note*: Heroku makes it clear that Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku is experimental, which means “no support, the ruby_version will change in the future, and this feature may change or be removed without warning.” In response to an inquiry on January 31, 2012, Heroku said, “there is no timeline yet” to fully support Ruby 1.9.3.

*Note*: Installing Ruby 1.9.3 on Heroku previously (before March 19, 2012) required installation of the heroku-labs plugin. The heroku-labs plugin is deprecated and its functionality is now incorporated in the heroku client gem.

Taken from [here](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)